# Android: get real in-app purchases instead of test purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Currently, I added a billing processor for my store. All test in-app purchases are working but when will they expire/remove for real IAP?

I would like to know where test IAP are based on.
Did I receive a test IAP because I am and a tester or just because the app is not released and still on beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Android Docs http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

> Test purchases offer a secure, convenient way to enable larger-scale testing of your In-app Billing implementation during development or in preparation for launch. They let authorized user accounts make purchases of your in-app products through Google Play while the app is still unpublished, without incurring any actual charges to the user accounts.
>
> Once authorized with testing access, those users can side-load your app and test the full merchandising, purchase, and fulfillment flow for your products. Test purchases are real orders and Google Play processes them in the same way as other orders. When purchases are complete, Google Play prevents the orders from going to financial processing, ensuring that there are no actual charges to user accounts, and automatically canceling the completed orders after 14 days.

During development, the purchases will be testing purchases because the app is not signed. On a signed release, they will be test purchases if the app is not published.